# Matlab trying to clean up ZipFile

Tags: matlab, zip

I have a zip file in my working folder, and it looks like Matlab is trying to do something with it without prompting. After my last session timed out, I got the following message:

```
Cleaning up unclosed ZipFile for archive \\filepath\folder\folder\file.zip
```

It was red, but didn't say anything additional about it being an error. I'm pretty sure I did  have that zipfile open in WinZip. However, I've also gotten this error while running long run-time scripts, and it seems to bomb them. Nothing in my scripts tells Matlab to even touch that file.

Any idea why Matlab is doing this, and what I can do to stop it?

Comment: Usually MATLAB takes control of the current folder and for instance, if the folder is on an external harddisk, while the matlab process is running you cannot unmount the drive because matlab keeps the folder open. But it never makes changes to the files in the folder. Providing more info (OS, version, MATLAB version, ...) would be useful to answer the question.

Comment: MATLAB's Current Folder browser allows inspection into *.zip files; it's likely related to this. MathWorks' technical support is probably a better place to ask this question.

Comment: I'm running MATLAB 2015a on Windows 7.

Comment: Same for MATLAB R2019b on Windows 10.